# Possible to show or access the full menu in Firefox 82 on Ubuntu 20?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, linux-mint

I just came from Linux Mint 18 where there was an extensive menu in Firefox at the top of the screen. Ubuntu seems to have hidden this. Is it possible to show or access the full Firefox menu? In particular I'm looking for the reopen closed tab function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on tab menu and click on `Menu Bar` option. Here you can toggle on and off the `Menu Bar`.

Comment: Got it, thanks. The tab menu is the three lines on the top right.

Comment: @gornvix Have you succeeded toggling on the Menu Bar? The tab bar is the bar on which tabs are located, and the "three lines button" you are describing is actually the modern replacement for the `Menu Bar`. If my answer is the solution to your problem, you should accept the answer, so your question should be considered successfully answered.